# Batch file: FOR outputting whole string as a single line with spaces

Tags: batch-file, variables, curl, output

I need to save the output of a `curl` command to a variable. The only issue is that the output contains spaces and the `for` command splits them on different lines (the output variable only contains the first block of characters).

Code:

```
for /F usebackq %%I in (`curl "https://api.checkwx.com/metar/cyyz?x-api-key=c6e048117df34d45871ca85e73"`) do set output=%%I
    echo %output%
```

Outputs: `{"data":["CYYZ`

Instead of: `{"data":["CYYZ 221700Z 00000KT 15SM BKN220 05/M11 A3031 RMK CI7 SLP271"],"results":1}`

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Add `delims` into `for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ...`, else only the first `token` is used in `%%I` and the default token delimiters are space and tab

Comment: Please read the help information for the command you are using, instead of asking others how to use it. Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output. In the meantime I'd advise that the safest and quickest way would be to change your commandline to `For /F Tokens^=*^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe "https://api.checkwx.com/metar/cyyz?x-api-key=c6e048117df34d45871ca85e73" 2^>NUL') Do @Set "output=%%G"`. _You should note that there is no need at all to use back quotes, (it is very rare that you would need to do so)._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [@jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) your solution works.

In regards to [@Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo)'s answer, I read the [official Microsoft online documentation regarding the for command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for), but couldn't find a solution there.
It seems like the actual problem was with my . I didn't know they were supposed to be quoted and looking at the examples in the documentation, none were. I tried `delims=` before but the batch file simply crashed upon that command.